# Ubuntu Logs and Monitoring

Tags: logging, ubuntu-10.04

I am writing simple program for my Ubuntu 10.04.
I want to see which files were used by processes. Where I can see what file was requested by the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any log files which list past files that had been opened by a process but I know of a couple ways to determine what files a process opens.

Using strace (system call trace) you can find out what files a program opens:

```
strace -e trace=open <path_to_executable>
```

You could also try using lsof (list open files) to determine what files are currently open by running processes.